# Why response error the function through the LB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, load-balancing

I'm trying to connect Cloud Load balancer to my Firebase functions with serverless NEG.
serverless NEG settings is setting below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez5Iz.png

But response is 404 error.

I using this code

```
import express from 'express'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { appSendError } from '../../utils/app/error/error'
import { appSendSuccess } from '../../utils/app/common'

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  try {
    return appSendSuccess({
      res,
      message: 'success',
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return appSendError({
      res,
      error,
    })
  }
})

export const api_test = functions
  .region('asia-northeast1')
  .https.onRequest(app)
```

My requesing is reached api.
[Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peIB2.png) [Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryXLn.png)

Do someone know about this problem...?

Please help me!!

Thank you.

Comment: Please translate your image into English.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just translated image into English

Comment: Seems like you're reaching the function. What does the function is supposed to do? As well how are you calling the function?

Comment: @FerreginaPelona The function is simple get function(region is asia-northeast1) for test of function.

Comment: @RetsukiYoneichi And how you call the function through the LB?

Comment: @FerreginaPelona I setting LB to DNS. And then I call the LB(https://example.com/api_test). LB is routed the function(cloudfunctions.net/api_test) by serverless neg.

Comment: In fact all your settings and the way you call the function is ok so I'd say the issue is your code and how it handles the request. Please edit your question and show the code used in your function. This is because actually is the function itself the one returning the 404, not the LB

Comment: @FerreginaPelona  I just changed question and please check it!!